# RecyclerView animate Toolbar also when its not scrollable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tablayout, android-appbarlayout

What happens :

Recyclerview only contains two rows so it's not scrollable, but when you swipe down the toolbar collapse and vice versa.

Expected :
   Toolbar animate when Recyclcer view is scrollable

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways" />


  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:scrollbars="none">

      </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: scrollbars="none"?.. Have you populated the recyclerview?

Comment: It contains two rows

Comment: What is your actual question? Please describe your problem in detail, what do you expect to happen, and what does happen instead?

Comment: should put more in order to give the opportunity to recyclerView to shake , and sect scrollbars = ' vertical '

Comment: @bgse i  edited my answer